# CSS transition , react-transition-group and React.findDOMnode deprecation

Tags: reactjs, react-transition-group, react-routing

I encountered a Warning relative to the findDOMnode deprecation when trying to use **react routing** in combination with **react-transition-group**, the warning stated:

*index.js:1 Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference. Learn more about using refs safely here: https://reactjs.org/link/strict-mode-find-node*

The above warning refers to the following code:

```
<Route  key={path} path={path} exact>

  
{({match})=>(

  <CSSTransition
 
  in={match!=null}
  timeout={300}
  classNames="page"
  unmountOnExit
  mountOnEnter
  
  >

    <div  className="page">
    
      <Component />
    </div>
  </CSSTransition>  

 )}

  </Route>)
```

**My first attempt of getting rid of that warning was to make use of useRef as suggested:**

```
const nodeRef = useRef(null);
```

passing nodeRef as ref prop of the CSStransation element but the warning was still showing up.

For some reason I could only get rid of the warning by passing the triggering event that I was also using in the 'in' prop of the CSStransition element, like showed here below:

```
 <Route  key={path} path={path} exact>

  
{({match})=>(

  <CSSTransition
  
  ref={nodeRef}
  in={match!=null}
  timeout={300}
  classNames="page"
  unmountOnExit
  mountOnEnter
  key={match!=null}    <------------ Adding this removed the warning
  >

    <div  className="page">
    
      <Component />
    </div>
  </CSSTransition>  

 )}

  </Route>)
```

Everything work smoothly now but I cant really undestand why, and even if I remove the the ref from the CSStransition element I dont get any warning anymore.

**Does anybody undestand why this is actually happening?**

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to figure this out as well, and I finally got it! You need to use the `nodeRef` prop in the `CSSTransition` for each route individually. Each route gets its own `ref`, and that `ref` needs to be assigned to the `nodeRef` accordingly. I was able to get this working by using an array of refs, mapping each route and assigning the refs to the current index.

Take a look at this working example I made:

- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-transition-routes-with-noderef-k9q47

And here's the block of code that is going to be the most helpful:

```
////// CONTENT TRANSITION ROUTER
const PageContent = withRouter(({ location }) => {
  let routeRefs: any[] = [];

  const isMatch = useCallback(
    (path: string): boolean => {
      return location.pathname === path ? true : false;
    },
    [location]
  );

  return (
    <>
      {appRoutes.map(({ path, Component }, index) => {
        routeRefs[index] = React.useRef(null);

        return (
          <Route key={index} exact path={path}>
            {() => {
              // Route callback ensures the transitions are loaded correctly
              return (
                <CSSTransition
                  nodeRef={routeRefs[index]}
                  in={isMatch(path)}
                  timeout={300}
                  classNames="fade"
                  unmountOnExit
                  appear
                >
                  <div ref={routeRefs[index]} className="fade">
                    <Component />
                  </div>
                </CSSTransition>
              );
            }}
          </Route>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
});
```